# Call Powershell Variable from Pipeline

Tags: python, rest, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running a build using a pipeline in Jenkins. 
I'm getting stuck at a point where I'm getting pipeline to call a REST method using Powershell and I want to print out the result of the REST call.

This is my code thus far

```
stage ('Call Powershell Script')
{
    node {
        powershell '$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://127.0.0.1:5000/doanalysis -Method Post -Body @{repo="DataCollection";pr="23";source="master2";destination="master"}'
        powershell 'Write-Host $result'
    }
}
```

The REST call is working properly. It actually makes a post call to a web application I have set up using Flask.
However, I am unable to display the output properly. The output should just be a string.
I have control of the web application so I can make it return whatever format necessary.

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Call Powershell Script)
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PR Projects\jobs\PR Pipeline2\workspace
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] powershell
[workspace] Running PowerShell script
[Pipeline] powershell
[workspace] Running PowerShell script
ï»¿
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Furthermore, if I just try to do 'echo $result' outside of Powershell, it says it doesn't exist.

Is there a way to make REST calls from pipeline? I'm using Jenkins so I have access to pipeline plugins on Jenkins.
Is there a way for me to access variables in powershell from pipeline?
Or is there any way to fix what I'm currently doing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think each `powershell` call is it's own session. Does just `powershell '$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://127.0.0.1:5000/doanalysis -Method Post -Body @{repo="DataCollection";pr="23";source="master2";destination="master"}; $result'` work?

Comment: @BenH Yeah it does! Thanks